# Get value from select with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

On my homepage (home.php) I have a first script who take some result of php page (test.php) and display on div #details-menu.
It's the list of "product" table from database.
After when result is selected, I would like to validate it and display on alert.
But it doesn't work... Some idea to help me ?

Here my code :

HOME.PHP (jquery code)

```
// First display the list of idcat
$(".displaymenu").on('click', function()
{
            var idcat=1;
            $.ajax({                                                            
            type: "GET",
            url: "test.php",
            data: "idcat="+idcat+"",
            success: function(msg){
            $("#details-menu").html(msg);
                } 
            });
}); 

// Second validate the choice after selected one product
$('#details-menu').on('click', '.validproduct', function() {
var idproduct=$(this).attr("choice_idproduct");
alert(idproduct);
});
```

HOME.PHP (html code) :

```
<div id="details-menu"></div>
```

TEST.PHP :

```
<?php
$idcat=$_GET['idcat'];
echo '<select id="choice_idproduct">';
    $result = mysql_query("select * from myproduct where idcat='$idcat'");
    while ($r_prod = mysql_fetch_array($result_prod)) 
    {
        echo '<option value="'.$r_prod['idproduct'].'">'.$r_prod['nameproduct'].'</option>';
    }
echo '</select>';
echo '<div class="validproduct">VALIDATE</div>';
?>
```

Comment: $("#details-menu").html(msg); } syntax error here?

Comment: Guess you need to change the var ```idproduct=$(this).attr("choice_idproduct");``` to ```var idproduct=$('#choice_idproduct');``` Now you try to get an attribute, but in your PHP file it's the id.

Comment: Thank You erik, but if I do that I have on my alert [object Object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get an attribute of your div, what is not exists. `#choice_idproduct` is the child of the div, not an attribute.

Get the value of the select instead.

Try this:

```
var idproduct=$("#choice_idproduct").val();
```